# Open terminal on startup and run command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

Very simple question, I'm new to Linux

I have a command run on startup (Elementary OS) command is:

```
/home/zachary/Documents/Server108/Server108.sh
```

When I turn my laptop on the command runs in the background, and this is great, but I can't issue a "Stop" command because the terminal never opens. So, my question is this;

How do I force the terminal to open, run the script and then stay open?
Do I need to add a line to the .sh file, or add arguments to the startup command?

Comment: You might be able to make a desktop file and set the `Terminal=` option to true.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, I'm using the default folders application that came with Elementary OS

Comment: @Zacharee1 How do I do this?

Comment: You could learn how to store the `pid` somewhere and kill that specific process.  `upstart` `systemd`

Comment: Just commenting, that there's a stackexchange community dedicated to Elementary OS here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

If you are using older GNOME you can add to startup something like this:

> gnome-terminal --command "/path/myscript.sh"

Just edit your startup with `gnome-session-properties` GUI. It should be in *System -> Properties* menu or *Applications –> Other –> Advanced Settings* or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and input it there. But apparently it was deprecated and it will not work on GNOME 3...

You can try adding into your folder `~/.config/autostart` a file, let's say `myscript.desktop` with following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --command "/path/myscript.sh"
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Startup Script
Comment=
```

Above content is actually from my own system, created by `mate-session-properties` GUI and it works. Only updated it for GNOME. It actually might work on other environments, you'll just need to play with some details. Adding `Terminal=true` with `Exec=/path/myscript.sh` also works and with it you don't need to know the command to start your terminal.

On MATE it's easier, because it's still got that GUI. Commands are called `mate-terminal` and `mate-session-properties`. Here's how it looks on my MATE:

[image]

I'm not familiar with Elementary OS and you didn't say which desktop environment you are using (might be Pantheon which I've never worked on), but it should not be that different.
You might need to figure out command to start your terminal and try running `my-terminal --help` or visit it's manpages to find proper parameter (or just try that much simpler `Terminal=true` solution).

And if for some reason `Terminal=true` doesn't work and you can't determine your terminal's commands, install XTerm:

> sudo apt-get install xterm

Its command is `xterm -e "/path/myscript.sh`.

Comment: I tried adding the "gnome..." command to the startup menu, and tried adding "mate-terminal" to the script, neither opens the terminal.  Am I doing something wrong? Maybe instead of trying to open the file with terminal, we could open terminal with a command to open the script already running? If that makes sense.  So I turn it on, Terminal opens and automatically runs the command "sh /home/zachary/Documents/Server108/Server108.sh"? Because doing this manually provides the desired results? Is that possible?

Comment: You sure you have gnome-terminal installed? Maybe your OS have different default terminal? Open your terminal and input `gnome-terminal --help` :) I've never heard about opening terminal for already running process... And "sh /script.sh" won't work. I've tested my command and it works with startup and with Caja-Actions. Plus where are you entering that startup command? Ubuntu's got special GUI tool for startup programs.

Comment: Updated my original answer, it should be more clear now.